# What arguments are passed into AsyncTask<arg1, arg2, arg3>?

Tags: android, arguments, android-asynctask

I don't understand what I am supposed to put in here and where these arguments end up? What exactly should I put, and where exactly will it go? Do I need to include all 3 or can I include 1,2,20?

Answer (score 511, accepted):

Google's Android Documentation Says that :

An asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params, Progress and Result, and 4 steps, called onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute.

AsyncTask's generic types :

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

```
Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
Result, the type of the result of the background computation.
```

Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type Void:

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }
```

You Can further refer : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Or You Can clear whats the role of AsyncTask by refering [Sankar-Ganesh's Blog](http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/p/need-and-vital-role-of-asynctas-in.html)

### Well The structure of a typical AsyncTask class goes like :

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<X, Y, Z>

    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }
```

This method is executed before starting the new Thread. There is no input/output  values, so just initialize variables or whatever you think you need to do.

```
    protected Z doInBackground(X...x){

    }
```

The most important method in the AsyncTask class. You have to place here all the stuff you want to do in the background, in a different thread from the main one. Here we have as an input value an array of objects from the type “X” (Do you see in the header? We have “...extends AsyncTask” These are the TYPES of the input parameters) and returns an object from the type “Z”.

```
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Y y){

   }
```

This method is called using the method publishProgress(y) and it is usually used when you want to show any progress or information in the main screen, like a progress bar showing the progress of the operation you are doing in the background.

```
  protected void onPostExecute(Z z){

  }
```

This method is called after the operation in the background is done. As an input parameter you will receive the output parameter of the doInBackground method.

**What about the X, Y and Z types?**

As you can deduce from the above structure:

```
 X – The type of the input variables value you want to set to the background process. This can be an array of objects.

 Y – The type of the objects you are going to enter in the onProgressUpdate method.

 Z – The type of the result from the operations you have done in the background process.
```

How do we call this task from an outside class? Just with the following two lines:

```
MyTask myTask = new MyTask();

myTask.execute(x);
```

Where x is the input parameter of the type X.

Once we have our task running, we can find out its status from “outside”. Using the “getStatus()” method.

```
 myTask.getStatus();
```

and we can receive the following status:

**RUNNING** - Indicates that the task is running.

**PENDING** - Indicates that the task has not been executed yet.

**FINISHED** - Indicates that onPostExecute(Z) has finished.

***Hints about using AsyncTask***

1. Do not call the methods onPreExecute, doInBackground and onPostExecute manually. This is automatically done by the system.
2. You cannot call an AsyncTask inside another AsyncTask or Thread. The call of the method execute must be done in the UI Thread.
3. The method onPostExecute is executed in the UI Thread (here you can call another AsyncTask!).
4. The input parameters of the task can be an Object array, this way you can put whatever objects and types you want.

Answer (score 95):

I'm too late to the party but thought this might help someone.

[image]

Comment: This visual was extremely helpful.  I am going to start using more visuals like this to show how Types and their related variables are tied together when the code flow isn't straightforward or the technique or pattern uncommon.  I hope others will do more of this.  Thanks

Comment: Nice visuals, can you please add for WeakAsyncTask also?

Comment: @kAmol sure, I'll try to make a flow for `WeakAsyncTask` as well

Comment: One day I'll frame this and put it on my wall so I don't have to keep coming back to this thread for reference.

Answer (score 20):

## Keep it simple!

An `AsyncTask` is background task which runs in the background thread. It takes an **Input**, performs **Progress** and gives **Output**.

> ie `AsyncTask<Input,Progress,Output>`.

In my opinion the main source of confusion comes when we try to memorize the parameters in the `AsyncTask`.
The key is **Don't memorize**.
If you can visualize what your task really needs to do then writing the `AsyncTask` with the correct signature would be a piece of cake.
Just figure out what your **Input**, **Progress** and **Output** are and you will be good to go.

**For example:**
[image]

### Heart of the AsyncTask!

`doInBackgound()` method is the most important method in an `AsyncTask` because

- Only this method runs in the background thread and publish data to UI thread.
- Its signature changes with the `AsyncTask` parameters.

> So lets see the relationship

[image]

> `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()`,`onProgressUpdate()` are also related

[image]

**Show me the code**
So how will I write the code for DownloadTask?

```
DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{

      @Override
      public void onPreExecute()
      {}

      @Override
      public String doInbackGround(String... params)
      {
               // Download code
               int downloadPerc = // calculate that
               publish(downloadPerc);

               return "Download Success";
      }

      @Override
      public void onPostExecute(String result)
      {
          super.onPostExecute(result);
      }

      @Override
      public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params)
      {
             // show in spinner, access UI elements
      }

}
```

**How will you run this Task**

```
new DownLoadTask().execute("Paradise.mp3");
```

Comment: `// show in spinner, access UI elements` was just hands down the most straightforward explanation for the `onProgressUpdate(...)` :)

Answer (score 6):

Refer to following links:

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
2. http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/

You cannot pass more than three arguments, if you want to pass only 1 argument then use void for the other two arguments.

```
1. private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> 


2. protected class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Integer>
```

An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread. An asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params, Progress and Result, and 4 steps, called onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute.

Answer (score 3):

- in Short, There are 3 parameters in AsyncTask

  1. parameters for Input use in DoInBackground(String... params)
  2. parameters for show status of progress use in OnProgressUpdate(String... status)
  3. parameters for result use in OnPostExcute(String... result)

  Note : - [Type of parameters can vary depending on your requirement]