# Error while trying to upload file from android

Tags: php, android

I am trying to upload a file from the simulator to a php server. While there is nothing wrong in logcat or http error log, I don't see the file where it is supposed to be. The server responds with HTTP_OK. Here is the upload function

```
public void uploadPic() {
    ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);

    Log.e("@@@@@@@@@", "Uploadpic called");
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String pathToOurFile = "/data/icon.jpg";
    String urlServer = "http://192.168.1.9/savepic2.php";
    //String urlServer = "http://winlab.rutgers.edu/~achanda";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    try
    {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile));

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Enable POST method
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );

    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    //serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    Log.e("@@@@@@@", connection.getResponseMessage());

    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Here is the PHP code

```
    <?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]. "<br />";

        $target_path = "uploads/";

        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)) {
                echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]).
                        " has been uploaded";
        }
        else{
                echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
}
?>
```

What else can go wrong here?

Comment: Does PHP issue any of your echos at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing I believe your problem is ether todo with permissions within the manifest or the file dont exist on the emulator or device...

I got the following code to upload to my test server, I used a toast to output the error & a textview to show the result on success.

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test.upload"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AndroidUploadActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**AndroidUploadActivity.class**

```
package com.test.upload;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidUploadActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView textView1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        try {
            upload();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
            toast.show();  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void upload() throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = "/sdcard/DCIM/test.png";
        String urlServer = "http://192.168.2.1/androidupload/index.php";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile));
            URL url = new URL(urlServer);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream
                    .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                            + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);

            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            textView1.setText(serverResponseMessage);

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView android:text="" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**PHP (Note this is very insecure):**

```
<?php
$target_path  = "./";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, this works fine for me. I guess it was a problem with permissions somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the same coding but am getting Internal server Error.I couldn't found what is the cause, can u pls help me

Comment: I am gettin following message : 204 No Content.

Comment: For future reference, this method should be done in the background of an AsyncTask. Tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053602/what-arguments-are-passed-into-asynctaskarg1-arg2-arg3