# Accessing an Object from outside of AsyncTask

Tags: android

I need to access an Object from AsyncTask.
Here's the code of the AsyncTask:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}
```

I want to access `data`. I have no idea how can I do it.

Comment: Make it a `global` variable

Comment: When you return `data` in `doInBackground` its used as input parameter for `onPostExecute`. So at the moment whats happening is youre passing `data` to your `parserTask`

Comment: Why do you need it? result and data is the same string in your AsyncTask

Comment: I want to access data/result from another activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053602/what-arguments-are-passed-into-asynctaskarg1-arg2-arg3 check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative approch is that you declare `data` variable with private static modifier and create a public static get Method. From the second activity can directly access that public static method.

```
private class FirstAcitivity extends Activity
{
    private static String data = "";

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            //String data = "";                                                    // Comment this line 

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    public static String getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Now access in Second Activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity 
{ 
    String data = FirstActivity.getData();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also access it by declaring the variable as following:

```
 public static String data="";
```

Then you can access it in other Activity as:

```
 ClassName.data
```

where ClassName will be the name of class where you defined the variable.

Comment: While this is true answer but you shouldn't use public variable instead you should use private variable with public method, like I did.