# how to return result from asyn call

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

i have all my async calls in their own classes and so i dont want to have global vars being set aync'ly. To do this i want to return objects eg a string from my asunc postProcess methods.

can this be done?

Below is my general structure to my classes, i want to return a String for example from onPostExecute(). I see delegates are mentioned in other places but this seems very messy, sure there is a way to have a return type to the class or methods?

```
class GetStuffAsyncly extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    // my vars....

    public myconstructor(String dialogMessage, Context con)
    {
        this.qDialog =  new ProgressDialog(con);
        this.dialogString = dialogMessage;
        this.context = con;
    }

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        do stuff like fire dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {
       // do stuff in background...

        return data;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString)
    {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all data
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: using a callback (interface) is the proper way

Comment: Thx for the response Boss. If possible, can you extend my code to demo a callback?

Comment: Check the answer of this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053602/what-arguments-are-passed-into-asynctaskarg1-arg2-arg3

Comment: check @Nigam Patro's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some thing like below

```
class GetStuffAsyncly extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String dialogString;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Context context;
    AsyncListener listener;
    // my vars....

    public GetStuffAsyncly(String dialogMessage, Context con, AsyncListener listener) {
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(con);
        this.dialogString = dialogMessage;
        this.context = con;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        listener.onTaskStarted();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // do stuff in background...

        return data;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all data
        dialog.dismiss();
        listener.onTaskFinished(jsonString);
    }
}
```

And the listener class

```
public interface AsyncListener {
    void onTaskStarted();

    void onTaskFinished(String data);
}
```

and you can call like this

```
new GetStuffAsyncly(message, this, new AsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTaskStarted() {
                //do your stuff
            }

            @Override
            public void onTaskFinished(String data) {
//Do your stuff;
            }
        }).execute(parameter);
```

Comment: Great thx. One question, how do i use the Listener class AsyncListener, i presume i call this from whereever i want to return my data to but how do i call it?

Comment: Ok i'll give this a go. Where do i specify what var is returned from the postExecute? Is it listener.onTaskFinished(jsonString);?

Comment: And where do i retrieve the data from? where you say //do your stuff? what var contains the data from postexecute? my aim os to get the resulting data from async into my activity - where does it enter the activiity from?

Comment: @Fearghal you call AsyncTask some where in your activity, and after background execution it will come to **onPostExecute()** and it will call **onTaskFinished()**.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `AsyncTaskLoader`. You derive your class not from `AsyncTask`, but from `AsyncTaskLoader`. In your Activity you need to implement `LoaderCallbacks` interface. The args you want to use in Loader, you put in Bundle. All information you want to get from Loader will be passed in method `onLoadFinished()`. Here's an example

```
 public class BaseInitLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Employee[]> {
        Context mContext;
        boolean firstrun;

        public BaseInitLoader(Context context, Bundle args) {
            super(context);
            mContext = context;
            firstrun = args.getBoolean("firstrun");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            super.onStartLoading();
            forceLoad();
        }

        @Override
        public Employee[]  loadInBackground() {
            MainActivity activity =(MainActivity) mContext;



            Cursor cursor = new DatabaseFiller(activity.getDb(), mContext, firstrun).fillTable();
            ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
            QueryResultIterable<Employee> itr = null;

            try {

                 itr = cupboard().withCursor(cursor).iterate(Employee.class);
                for(Employee employee: itr){
                    list.add(employee);
                }


            } finally {
                // close the cursor
                if (itr != null) {
                    itr.close();
                }
            }
            Employee[] employees = new Employee[list.size()];
            employees = list.toArray(employees);
            return employees;
        }
    }
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks, View.OnClickListener {

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    TextView priority, name, innerPhone, mobilePhone, position;
    Button cityBtn;
    CharSequence[] cities;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Context mContext;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ListView listView;
    private TextView nameTxt;
    private EmployeeAdapter adapter;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "Database";
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    private boolean firstrun;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;


    private final int INITIAL = 1;
    private final int SORT_NAME = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("ua.lanet.PipBoy", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)){
            args.putBoolean("firstrun", true);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).apply();

        }
        else{
            args.putBoolean("firstrun", false);
        }


        getLoaderManager().initLoader(INITIAL, args, this);


        PipBoyDataHelper helper = new PipBoyDataHelper(this);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}


    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return db;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    return new BaseInitLoader(mContext, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Object data) {

       //do something with the data. Cast Object to your return type of loader

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.text:
                getLoaderManager().initLoader(SORT_NAME, null, this);
                break;
        }
    }



    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }
    }

}
```