# A `doInBackground()` of type void is not accepted by `AsyncTask`?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

As seen from [Google's Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) we see that

> *Params*, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
>
> *Progress*, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
>
> *Result*, the type of the result of the background computation.

also mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6053673/4126843) excellent answer.

**But then, why does having `Void` as result type result in the following warning by Android Studio on the `doInBackground` line:**

```
doInBackground(String...)' in '(..)MainActivity.myTask' clashes with 'doInBackground(Params...)' in 'android.os.AsyncTask'; attempting to use incompatible return type
```

This is how the `AsyncTask` is declared:

```
private class myTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(String... url) {
        //do stuff with url[0]
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        //more stuff
    }
}
```

In comparison, this seems to work fine:

```
private class myTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        //do stuff with url[0]
        return "hi";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //more stuff
    }
}
```

Note there are various questions about this topic, but most of them just messed up the `AsyncTask` parameters or parameters and return values in the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this code

```
 private class myTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {
          //do stuff with url[0]
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //more stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that use of `Void` passing on the null, thanks!