# Getting data from async task onpostexecute using interface

Tags: java, android, interface, android-asynctask

Hi I am trying to get an arraylist of data from a an async task class to another main class:

I was following the answer below but I am a little lost:

[How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

So I have my class that extends async task and calls to the database to get my object array:

```
public class GetVideoInfoFromDataBase extends AsyncTask {

    // Paginated list of results for song database scan
    static PaginatedScanList<AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter> results;

    // The DynamoDB object mapper for accessing DynamoDB.
    private final DynamoDBMapper mapper;

    public interface AlarmsDataBaseAsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(PaginatedScanList<AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter> output);
    }

    public AlarmsDataBaseAsyncResponse delegate = null;

    public GetVideoInfoFromDataBase(AlarmsDataBaseAsyncResponse delegate){
        mapper = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getDynamoDBMapper();
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
        results = mapper.scan(AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter.class, scanExpression);
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Object obj) {

        delegate.processFinish(results);

    }
}
```

There are no errors but I think I have done something incorrectly in it causing my error.

So in my main activity to call the results I have:

```
GetVideoInfoFromDataBase asyncTask =new GetVideoInfoFromDataBase(new GetVideoInfoFromDataBase.AlarmsDataBaseAsyncResponse(){


    @Override
    public void processFinish(PaginatedScanList<AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter> output) {

    }
}).execute();
```

I have two problems here

1. I am getting the error:
   `"incompatible types: AsyncTask cannot be converted to GetVideoInfoFromDataBase"`

In the mainactivity where i have:

```
`new GetVideoInfoFromDataBase(new GetVideoInfoFromDataBase.AlarmsDataBaseAsyncResponse()`
```

it wants me to cast it like this:

```
(GetVideoInfoFromDataBase) new GetVideoInfoFromDataBase(new GetVideoInfoFromDataBase.AlarmsDataBaseAsyncResponse()
```

That doesn't seem right but I thought i would check.

2. I am not sure how to return the result when overriding the onprocessfinished.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053602/what-arguments-are-passed-into-asynctaskarg1-arg2-arg3

Comment: @skadoosh This does not include anything about interfaces?

Comment: its about parameters of AsyncTask as you current implementation is not correct in terms of its Parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create an Interface

```
public interface AsyncInterface {
    void response(String response);
}
```

Assign it in the asynctask class as below :-

```
Context context;
Private AsyncInterface asyncInterface;

AsyncClassConstructor(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    this.asyncInterface = (AsyncInterface) context;
}
```

Then inside onPostExecute method of asynctask class :-

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    asyncInterface.response(s);
}
```

Then implement this interface in your activity :-

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncInterface {
```

and then import the method of asyncInterface

```
@Override
public void response(String response) {
    //Here you get your response
    Log.e(TAG, response);
}
```

Comment: So the last part override response calls the async class? I am not sure how that is running?

Comment: As soon as AsyncTask class reches to PostExecute method after finishing the background task, It will send result data to mainactivity using interface

Comment: Ok but how do you call the async class? It asks for the context and the asyncinteface as parameters when calling

Comment: new AsyncClass(Context, ?)

Comment: Sorry I added AsyncInterface there by mistake. you should pass only Context there as new AsyncClass(MainActivity.this)

Comment: Using you code it asks for two arguments. Context and async interface when calling the Async class. Niot sure what is goin on?

Comment: Actually my mistake

Comment: I edited my answer, you should remove asyncInterface from constructor

Comment: @i_m_mahani I just tried it and I am getting a null pointer for async interface. I will modify my code so you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Modify Constructor of class. 
Need default constructor. By the way, create method to set Interface.

```
public void setInterface(AlarmsDataBaseAsyncResponse delegate){
         this.delegate = delegate;}
```

In MainActivity, push your logic in:

```
  object.setInterface(new AlarmsDataBaseAsyncResponse(){
        @Override
        public void processFinish(PaginatedScanList<AlarmDynamoMappingAdapter> output) {
              //your logic
        }
  });
```

Comment: I don't understand your solution. it seems like the first part of this is alreeady in my code.

Comment: You miss method super in default constructor 's  children class