# How pass method in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I've class with methods

```
class Wrapper {

  public static String AuthIn(String Login, String Password){
    String response = HTTPRequest.POST(client, GetAuthUrl(), RequestBuilder.AuthInVk(login, password));
                    System.out.println(response);
  }

  public static String GetInfoUser(){
     String response = HTTPRequest.GET(client, "http://site1.com");
     System.out.println(response);
  }
}
```

When i call this methods in MainActivity class and get error message "Main thread ..... etc"

How write  Wrapper class in AsyncTask ?

Comment: please rework your question, it´s not really understandable

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice example taken from [codexpedia](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/asynctask-and-httpurlconnection-sample-in-android/), for more details please check their site.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvWeatherJson;
    Button  btnFetchWeather;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvWeatherJson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_json);
        btnFetchWeather = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fetch_weather);
        btnFetchWeather.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new FetchWeatherData().execute();
            }
        });
    }


    private class FetchWeatherData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0");

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                return forecastJsonStr;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally{
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            tvWeatherJson.setText(s);
            Log.i("json", s);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to pass data into the async task doInBackground or onPostExcute and more check this stackoverflow comment : [what-arguments-are-passed-into-asynctaskarg1-arg2-arg3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053602/what-arguments-are-passed-into-asynctaskarg1-arg2-arg3)

Keep in mind that your AsyncTask won't stop even when the activity has destroyed. A better way to create a network call from an activity is with an [Handler](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) Or just use an asyncHttp client lib such as [ok-http](https://github.com/square/okhttp) , [google volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) :)

Answer (score 0):

You always must perform network request form other thread than UI thread.  So you can create abstarct class (network dispatcher) which extend AsyncTask or Thread or Runnable and add abstarct method which will be called in run/doInBackground/etc. Next implement abstarct method in your method. But it a little improvement to your boilerplate code. Also you can use JavaRx (AndroidRx) to perform networking method. Also you can use Retrofit with JavaRx.

**EDIT**

I see you edit your question. If you want use AsyncTask you should implement it and perform request in doInBackgroud

Comment: Each method (authin, getuserinfo) put in doInBackground ?