# Simplest straight forward way to get a JSON String from a REST URL

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get a JSON string from a url and save it into SQLite in my android app.

I was trying some tutorials then realize the suggested methods has a void return type.  Are there a more simple straight forward way of getting a JSON String and putting it into an arraylist ready to be saved into SQLite?

Below is what I was stuck at a helper class that gets the data from the url
as they said that the main thread OnCreate does not allow a background process like this. Is there a way to change the return type of AsyncTask or is there a more simple way to fetch JSON String with android?

```
public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.403.211/api/wordsupdate.php");


            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line ="";
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }       

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: so you want to do it without any 3rd party library? if so, your code is ok, if not, use [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: No, the code is **not** ok, see my answer below

Comment: You can use Retrofit or Volley to download the JSON file, then in can be easily parsed with Gson. I would go with Retrofit and Gson, but this is just my preference

Comment: `most simple straight forward` is completely opinion-based. Nobody knows which way is `most simple straight forward` for **you**.

Comment: @lulian Popescu I ended up using Volley.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Retrofit is too complicated for me at the moment I want a simpler way just to grasp the concept in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with Volley API. Check the code below which demonstrate POST request. Hope you'll get useful information.

```
public void getAddress(final String uid) {

    String url = "Add Url Here"; // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    JSONArray dataArray;
                    JSONObject jsonObject;

                    address_ids = new ArrayList<>();
                    address_names = new ArrayList<>();
                    address_line1 = new ArrayList<>();
                    address_line2 = new ArrayList<>();
                    address_state = new ArrayList<>();
                    address_district = new ArrayList<>();
                    address_taluka = new ArrayList<>();
                    address_pincode = new ArrayList<>();
                    address_status = new ArrayList<>();
                    address_default = new ArrayList<>();


                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

                        //adding response values to respective array
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                            //Creating a json object of the current index
                            JSONObject obj;
                            try {
                                //getting json object from current index
                                obj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                address_ids.add(obj.getString(TAG_ADDRESS_ID));
                                address_names.add(obj.getString(TAG_ADDRESS_NAME));
                                address_line1.add(obj.getString(TAG_ADDRESSLINE_FIRST));
                                address_line2.add(obj.getString(TAG_ADDRESSLINE_SECOND));
                                address_state.add(obj.getString(TAG_STATE));
                                address_district.add(obj.getString(TAG_DISTRICT));
                                address_taluka.add(obj.getString(TAG_TALUKA));
                                address_pincode.add(obj.getString(TAG_PINCODE));
                                address_status.add(obj.getString(TAG_ADDRESS_STATUS));

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //setting up response values to the fragment
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error:"+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);
                    address_name.setText("Name : " + address_names.get(0));
                    address.setText("Address : " + address_line1.get(0) + "," + address_line2.get(0) + "-" + address_pincode.get(0));
                    taluka.setText("Taluka : " + address_taluka.get(0));
                    district.setText("District : " + address_district.get(0));
                    state.setText("State : " + address_state.get(0));
                    mCircularProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Taking bit longer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("mk_address_id", address_id);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: I ended up using Volley but starting with a more simple code.  I will try you code and come back here after I get familiar with Volley.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link [from Android developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), you can find more info their.

In your code change the "extends" from

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

to

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
```

and the doInBackground method to

```
protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... voids)
```

and you will get the string back in the onPostExecute method

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to change the return types: Have a look at your `extends AsyncTask`: It says `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`.

According to [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), this means `<Params, Progress, Result>`.

This means that your 
`ArrayList<String>... voids` won't work too, because you have the `Params` part set to Void but try to get an `ArrayList<String>`.

So, to solve your problem, change the three `Void`s to whatever you need it to input and output.

However, to deserialize JSON you should use an external library (or use a 3rd party library for REST calls altogether).

Answer (score 1):

//AsyncTask has onPostExecute which will be called after background execution, where you will get the result in mainthread

```
class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.403.211/api/wordsupdate.php");

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            return builder.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Your result String is here which runs on MAIN THREAD
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example code on getting the String while I am on the main activity?

Answer (score 0):

**Retrofit 2** will help you - easy and simple

Edit : For Async task see the top answer here

[What arguments are passed into AsyncTask<arg1, arg2, arg3>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053602/what-arguments-are-passed-into-asynctaskarg1-arg2-arg3)

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet , you specified AsyncTask params types are Void. Void means , it does't have any return value. As per AsyncTask Syntax,
You have to specify three arguments.
1- InputType- DoInBanckground
2- ProgressType - Publish Progress.
3- OutputType - OnPostExecute.

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
Result, the type of the result of the background computation.

In your snippet doInBackground method and AsycTask types are mismatching .

For more information : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html