# Type of argument/value that is passed in a AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Just 3 simple questions about AsyncTasks.
If we declare this AsyncTask:

`private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>`

1- What type of value is passed to doInBackground() method? Is it URL?

2- What type of value is passed to the callback that informs the task progress?

3- What type of value is passed to the callback that is executed when the task ends?

Thank you all. Rest of a good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsyncTask consists of **Input Parameter Type, Progress Parameter Type, Result Type** respectively.
So in your case

```
DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>
```

`URL` is the Input Parameter Type

`Integer` is the  Progress Parameter Type

`Long` is the Result Type

1. What type of value is passed to doInBackground() method? Is it URL?

   Answer: Yes its the URL
2. What type of value is passed to the callback that informs the task
   progress?

   Answer: its `Integer`
3. What type of value is passed to the callback that is executed when
       the task ends?

   Answer : Its `Long` value and it is the value that is expected to
   return from `doInBackground` and passed as a callback to
   onPostExecute`.

[image: For Reference]

Comment: Nice explanation friend. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

- Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
- Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
- Result, the type of the result of the background computation.

`private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> { ... }`

So, to answer your question, URL is passed to doInBackground and Long is the return type.

Read more https://stackoverflow.com/a/6053673/5644761

Comment: So the answers to my questions are 1-URL, 2-Integer and 3-Long?

Comment: URL is passed to doInBackground and Long is returned